# How to use Android "external/..."

Tags: android, android-ndk

I see a couple [examples](http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/Android/OSDevelopment) of `Android.mk` files using resources from an `external` directory:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/tinyalsa/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtinyalsa
```

The Android NDK that I've downloaded doesn't include any `external` directory, but I do see it among the [Git repositories on Android](https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML). My question is: how do I make use of one of these items (specifically `platform/external/tinyalsa`)?

I imagine that I'm to download the repository and drop it into my NDK folder, but where? The directory tree is huge.

Comment: Those paths are referring to directories in the AOSP tree, i.e. the source code for Android itself.

Comment: @Michael : Thanks for the info. If that's so, how are we expected to use libraries in `external`? For instance, the page on Android audio sources says "If you use ALSA, we recommend `external/tinyalsa`": https://source.android.com/devices/audio/

Comment: That page looks like it's directed at phone manfufacturers, rather than application developers.